# Impedindo duplicidade de dados

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, exceção

Quero impedir que seja feito um cadastro de uma pessoa,cujo o CPF da mesma já esteja cadastrado. Tentei fazer algo mas da um erro, pois defini o campo CPF como *constraint*. Ao invés de dar o erro gostaria que fosse mostrado uma mensagem avisando que o CPF já esta cadastrado.

Dá esse erro:

[image: exceção]

Comment: Está utilizando o quê? WinForms, WPF, Asp.net MVC? Como está tentando inserir? Está utilizando Entity Framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso é o que se espera e é um comportamento correto. Só falta decidir o que fazer quando o erro ocorre.

Coloque o trecho do código que faz a operação em um `try-catch` e defina o que fazer quando o erro acontecer.

Tudo que estiver no bloco do `try` estará "protegido". Então quando a exceção ocorrer ela pode ser capturada no `catch` e neste bloco pode fazer o que deseja.

Como a pergunta não tem um código vou por alguma coisa genérica aqui:

```
try {
    MetodoQueTentaFazerUmCadastro();
    TudoDeuCerto(); //se der a exceção no método anterior nem executará isto
} catch (OracleException ex) when (ex.ErrorCode == 1) { //C# 6
    WriteLine("Este CPF já está cadastrando entre os funcionários");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/Filter2.cs).

Se não estiver usando o C# 6, ou superior, aí terá que transformar esse `when` em um `if` dentro do bloco do `catch`. Não é o ideal, mas funcionará.

```
try {
    MetodoQueTentaFazerUmCadastro();
    TudoDeuCerto(); //se der a exceção no método anterior nem executará isto
} catch (OracleException ex) {
    if (ex.ErrorCode == 1) {
        WriteLine("Este CPF já está cadastrando entre os funcionários");
    } //pode ser que queira usar um else para outros casos
}
```

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Cuidado para não abusar deste recurso, muita gente o faz. [Seria bom entender seu uso completamente antes de sair usado em outro lugares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o?sort=votes&pageSize=50).